# PHP, how to create an array from 1 to 365 without looping or brute force typing

Tags: php, arrays

Matlab has a simple syntax for this you would type `MyArray = [1:365]` and it will create an array with all integers from 1 to 365. How is this done in PHP? I know PHP's arrays are more like matlab struct types. Where there are keys-value pairs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy. Just use [`range`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
// Create a range from 1 to 365.
$MyArray = range(1,365);

// Dump the line array for debugging.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($MyArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the output of that `print_r` dump would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 12
    [12] => 13
    [13] => 14
    [14] => 15
    [15] => 16
    [16] => 17
    [17] => 18
    [18] => 19
    [19] => 20
    [20] => 21
    [21] => 22
    [22] => 23
    [23] => 24
    etc…
```

Answer (score 3):

The `range()` function will do this for you.

```
$array = range(1,365);
```

Comment: Thanks! Deleting this post before i loose too many points lol.